# GCP Internal Load balancer - Error: Request failed with status code 431

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-internal-load-balancer

As per our requirement, we are making GET Request, we send encoded string in url. Gradually the length of encoded string exceeds 5000 character and that is where we are getting 431 error.

It seems like we are hitting this: [Load Balancer quota limit](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/quotas#https-lb-header-limits)

debug: osrm: query start
debug: osrm: **Error : Error: Request failed with status code 431**
at createError (/home/sagar/Desktop/interpl/OSRM-response-check/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
at settle (/home/sagar/Desktop/interpl/OSRM-response-check/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:17:12)
at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/home/sagar/Desktop/interpl/OSRM-response-check/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:293:11)
at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:402:35)
at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1343:12)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
config: {

Comment: Solution: Do not use long query strings. Although officially there is no limit specified by RFC 2616, many security protocols and recommendations state that maxQueryStrings on a server should be set to a maximum character limit of 1024. While the entire URL, including the querystring, should be set to a max of 2048 characters. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48230425/8016720

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are hitting the URL request size (64KB). That limit unfortunately cannot be increased on GCP Loadbalancers.